# Compile and run a file.c using Tiny C Compiler on Windows

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction, tcc

Could I get a step by step on how to compile my file.c using Tiny C Compiler and Windows prompt?

Some questions I already have:

1. Where do I stick all TCC files from the download?
2. Do I have to compile stdio.h to use the printf function? (I'd like to do a 'Hello World').

This is what my file.c looks like:

```
// #include <stdio.h> // for printf 

int main(void){
printf("Hello Eric. You've compiled and run the program!  \n");
}
```

Thanks,

---

**EDIT 1**

So far I'm running it and getting the error: include file 'stdio.h' not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you put the files wherever you like.
2. no, you do not need to compile `stdio.h` in order to use the `printf()` function.

the tcc-distribution (tcc-0.9.25-win32-bin\tcc) consists of this:

```
 tcc.exe
 tiny_impdef.exe
 tiny_libmaker.exe
 include\
   stdio.h ...
 lib\
   libtcc1.a ...
 doc\
 examples\
```

if you do not tear that order apart, `tcc` should work out of the box (i compiled a hello.c seconds ago). if you separated the files or something else does not work:

```
% tcc.exe -Ipath/to/include/folder/of/tcc input.c -L/path/to/lib/folder/of/
```

by looking at the source code of `tcc` i found this:

```
/* on win32, we suppose the lib and includes are at the location
   of 'tcc.exe' */

char path[1024], *p;
GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, path, sizeof path);
p = tcc_basename(normalize_slashes(strlwr(path)));
```

so, per default it assumes the libs and the headers to be in the place right next to the `tcc.exe`.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what you are doing in that first chunk of code? Are those commands I enter into the prompt before running my code?

Comment: @Eric Brotto: the first block is the listing of the files in the tcc distribution. the second block is something you could type into your prompt.

Comment: Thanks and excuse me for my ignorance. So I basically just run that seccond block of code (the one liner) and I should be okay?

Comment: @Eric Brotto: if you keep the files of the tcc distribution intact, then you just run `tcc.exe file.c`

Comment: This worked! You rock! Thanks for getting back to my comments :)