# Tiny C Compiler on Windows Seven 7

Tags: c, gcc, windows-7, installation

How do I install and run **gcc** on windows 7 ultimate?

Comment: Why -ve vote??? He is already telling taht he is newbie here.

Comment: Also GCC isn't the same as the [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/)

Comment: on the description he is writing run gcc on windows 7

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The first thing you should learn about this site is that you should always search first before posting a question. The second (not true just here, but for all sites that allow you to post to the) is that you should read the [about] and [help] pages to learn about the site.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5031529/62576 if you are in fact asking about Tiny C and not gcc. (Your question mentions both, and they are not the same thing, any more than a Ford and a Ferrari are the same thing just because they're both generally called "cars".)

Comment: @haccks: Even questions by "newbies" need to make at least some sense and show some effort. The subject says "Tiny C compiler", the question asks about "gcc", and "how do I get, install, and run" isn't a question. You get it by downloading it, you install it by following the installation instructions or running the installer, and you run it by calling the executable to compile your source code. StackOverflow is not a "teach me to program starting from step 1" site.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run gcc then try cygwin http://www.cygwin.com/install.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install **TDM GCC** native gcc compiler for windows (work good in windows 8)

http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/