# How to run TCC (Tiny C Compiler) with cmd?

Tags: cmd, tcc

I am trying to use tiny C compiler with cmd, but I forgot how to locate the tcc files on cmd. 
How do I link cmd with tiny c compiler ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031529/compile-and-run-a-file-c-using-tiny-c-compiler-on-windows

Comment: I do not know how to launch the file.c by linking to tcc still